# Python script path

Tags: python, pythonpath

Lets assume following directories tree:

```
   /
    home/
     user/
       X/
         scripy.py
          Y/
            a.c
            b.c
```

I have a python script, with many commands using relative path, doing sth like this:

```
def f1(relative_path_to_a, relative_path_to_c):
    abs_path = PATH_TO_PLACE_FROM_SCRIPT_WAS_CALLED
    c_abs_path = abs_path + relative_path_to_c
    file_a = open(relative_path_to_a)
    file_a.write(c_abs_path)
    close()
```

As it found out, I need to use it on another machine, with different directories tree. There should also be a possibility to call script from other location, than the one where it is placed.
Changing all paths to absolute will take some time, but is not impossible. On the other hand, I come up with an idea to change path on the beginning of the script, to `/home/user/X` (I did it by adding one more python file to `X` directory and calling inside of it `abs_path = os.path.abspath(".")`, then in script.py I do `os.chdir(second_script.abs_path)`.

What are disadvantages of second solution? Are there any situations, where it can crash?

To be precise, in the second solution, i'm doing sth line this:

```
   /
    home/
     user/
       X/
         scripy.py
         second_scripy.py
          Y/
            a.c
            b.c

user@user:~$ pwd
/home/
user@user:~$ python user/X/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

To make programs reusable, they are expected to work relative to the *current working directory*, not *change the cwd* and not relative to the *location of the program*. So you should use something like:

```
# relative_path_to_a = 'Y/a.c'
# relative_path_to_c = 'Y/b.c'

def f1(relative_path_to_a, relative_path_to_c):
    c_abs_path = os.path.abspath(relative_path_to_c)
    a_abs_path = os.path.abspath(relative_path_to_a)
    with open(a_abs_path) as file_a:
        file_a.write(c_abs_path)
```

this means for user `X` you run

```
(cd /user/X && python script.py)  # modifies /user/X/Y/a.c
```

and for user `Z` you can reuse the script using

```
(cd /user/Z && python ../X/script.py)   # modifies /user/Z/Y/a.c
```